# Как записать массив чисел в файл?

Tags: c

Новичок в Си, не могу никак разобраться как записать массив обычных int'ов в файл.

Comment: Файл текстовый или бинарный?

Comment: создать массив -> открыть файл -> построчно записать массив в файл

Comment: @finally, это только для текстового представления возможно.

Comment: @0andriy так автор не уточнил, какой это файл

Answer (score 3):

Для хранения большого количества данных лучше использовать запись в бинарный файл с помощью `fwrite()` и чтение с `fread()`. В данном примере изображена раздельная запись и чтение массива данных с неизвестным количеством элементов (при записи массивов разной длинны следует перед ним записать его длину, т.к. эта операция поможет при чтении файла).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 10 //длина массива на запись и чтение

int main() {
    FILE *file = NULL;  //указатель
    int len = LEN;      //число элементов массива
    int ArrOut[LEN] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1};

    file = fopen("output.bin", "wb");   //wb - флаг на запись бинарного файла

    if (file == NULL) { //если нельзя создать или открыть
        printf("Error");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    //записываем число элементов в массиве (для его чтения далее)
    fwrite(&len, sizeof(int), 1, file); 
    /* &ArrOut - ссылка на массив, sizeof(int) - размер одного элемента,
     * len- кол-во элементов на запись, file - указатель на файл */
    fwrite(ArrOut, sizeof(int), len, file); //запись самого массива
    printf("Запись: %d\n", len);
    fclose(file);   //закрываем файл
    /***************/
    FILE *Read = fopen("output.bin", "rb"); //rb - флаг на чтение бинарного файла

    if (Read == NULL) { //если нельзя открыть
        printf("Error");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    int lenRead;    //здесь будет храниться число элементов для чтения в файле
    fread(&lenRead, sizeof(int), 1, Read);
    //выделяем память под массив для чтения
    int *ArrIn = (int*) malloc(lenRead*sizeof(int));    
    //читаем данные
    fread(ArrIn, sizeof(int), lenRead, Read);

    fclose(Read);   //закрываем файл

    printf("Кол-во элементов прочитано: %d \n", lenRead);
    printf("Массив: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < lenRead; i++)
        printf("%d ",ArrIn[i]);

    free(ArrIn);    //освобождаем память
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```